# React native navigation stucks on white screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am facing problem in react native navigation on low end devices, when I navigate to next screen it just stucks on navigation, showing the background color which `NavigationContainer` have, in my case showing white screen forever.
However if I switch to another app / home then come back to it again it again shows the page.

Code for NavigationContainer in `App.jsx` is below

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';


            <NavigationContainer
                    onReady={() => RNBootSplash.hide()}
                    theme={{ colors: { background: colors.BACKGROUND_PRIMARY } }}
                >
                    <Splash />
                    <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                        <Routes />
                    </GestureHandlerRootView>
            </NavigationContainer>
```

My `Routes.jsx` file is as below

```
//Sample routes data:

    const routes = [
        ...(!username
            ? [
                    {
                        id: 6,
                        route: routeConstants?.PROFILE,
                        component: Profile,
                    },
              ]
            : []),
        {
            id: 1,
            route: routeConstants.BOTTOM_NAVIGATION,
            component: BottomNavigation,
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            route: routeConstants?.FOLLOW_REQUESTS,
            component: FollowRequests,
        }
]

        <Stack.Navigator>
            {screens.map((screen) => (
                <Stack.Screen
                    key={screen?.id}
                    name={screen?.route}
                    component={screen?.component}
                    options={{ headerShown: false, headerBackVisible: false }}
                />
            ))}
        </Stack.Navigator>
```